# A Shul renting out their Parking lot to a church?

Tags: halacha

Rent Or as a donation to the Shul 
Any Sources either way?
Thank You
Eli

Comment: Are you asking if a shul is allowed to rent its parking lot to a church? Or allowed to donate the use of its parking lot? To do what? To set up a prayer space? To park cars? Please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/86494/edit) to give more background and improve the clarity of your question

Comment: And welcome to MY !